# Why Django doesn't find a modules which PyCharm finds well?

Tags: python, django

I tries to build my first Django project.
I've created 'superlist' project and 'lists' app inside. My project tree:

```
pycharm_project_folder
    |
     superlist
           |
            lists
            superlist
            manage.py
            ...
    |
     venv
```

My lists/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def home_page():
    """home page"""
    pass
```

My superlist/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from superlist.lists import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('/', views.home_page, name='home')
    # path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

My lists/test.py

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import resolve

from superlist.lists.views import home_page


class HomePageTest(TestCase):
    """тест домашней страницы"""

    def test_root_url_resolves_to_home_page_view(self):
        """корневой url преобразуется в представление домашней страницы"""
        found = resolve('/')
        self.assertEqual(found.func, home_page)
```

So, when I run

```
python3 manage.py test
```

I see

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'superlist.lists'

I don't understad why I got it because paths were suggested by PyCharm

Comment: Do you use the same venv as the one used for your Pycharm project?

Comment: I've created venv from PyCharm in the working folder first, then I've created django project in the same directory.
So, I have my venv folder on the same level with "superlist" root Django project folder

Comment: And with from ```from lists.views import home_page``` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Python3, you will want to use relative imports, especially when you have duplicated package names, like you do here. In `superlist/urls.py` try:

```
from .lists import views
```

This assumes the urls.py file is `superlist/urls.py` and not `superlist/superlist/urls.py`. If the latter is true, then it would be:

```
from .superlist.lists import views
```

Answer (score 1):

So, in the end I just marked superlist folder as a 'source folder' in PyCharm. It resolved my issue